# Ideal target weight to start running (C25k)

Tags: running, weight-loss, getting-in-shape

I'm a 24 year old male, roughly 6'0" and 235 pounds. I've been more active in the past, but grad school and a recent shoulder surgery, plus a completely sedentary desk job, have caused me to gain a good bit of weight.

I've done couch to 5k before, and I'd like to do it again to get back into running and to get in shape in general. However, I know running overweight is not ideal, and of course I'd like to avoid more injuries than I already have.

Would starting c25k be okay for someone of my weight, assuming I take it slow? If not, what might a target weight be I should look for after which it should be "safe" for me to start running again?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the correct response is going to be, consult with your doctor before you make a change like this.

That said, I would start doing the C25K now if I were you; a few years ago, I started and I was 10 years older than you and 300 lbs.

Answer (score 0):

I say start now. The program really does ease you into it. The worst that happens, you repeat the first week again until you can work up past the initial 15 seconds of running.